# Why doesn't [[a-z]*&&[^a]] catch "bc", but "b"?

Tags: java, regex

Ok, so I have tried to become more familiar with the intersection in regex (`&&`).
On the [`java.util.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) page all the regex are explained and `&&` is only ever used next to a range (like `[a-z&&[^e]]`). But I tried to use it like this: `[[a-z]*&&[^a]]`. To me it seemed logical that this would match all lower case strings, expect the string `"a"`, but instead it seems to be equivalent with `[a-z&&[^a]]`.

So **the actual question is**: Where did the `*` operator go? How does this only catch single character strings?

Comment: And if you do want to provide a regex which does what I want: The regex would have to match `"abc"` as well. To quote myself: "all lower case strings, expect the string "a""

Comment: what makes this a bad question? tell me and I will fix it, just down voting won't ever help this question to increase in quality..

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose when people struggle to understand something, it is often because they don't know where the fault lies. if i had known that my problem was due to character classes, i would have read that bit. point is, *you could have known that if you had looked it up at resource XY* is pretty much what you could tell 99% of people asking questions on SO. The struggle is not to know where your question is answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a *character class* (marked by `[]`) the `*` character has no special meaning. It simply represents the character itself.

So the regular expression

```
[[a-z]*&&[^a]]
```

allows exactly one character being one of the following:

```
b, c, d, ..., z, *
```

The `[a-z]` and the following `*` are unioned, and the resulting character class is intersected with `[^a]` which simply removes the `a` character.

Valid strings are (for example):

```
b
*
c
```

But

```
a
```

is not, as well as each string that contains more than one character.

Now to the solution for what you want. You want to have strings (allowing more than one character, I assume) that could also contain the letter 'a' but not the string "a" alone. The easiest is a group that does this distinction:

```
(?!a$)[a-z]*
```

The group `(?!a$)` is called a *zero-width negative lookahead*. It means that the looked at character is not consumed (zero-width), and it is not allowed (negative). The '$' character looks till the end. Otherwise, words beginning with 'a' would also be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is wrong to use an intersection: To match all lowercase strings except `"a"`:

```
^(?!a$)[a-z]+$
```

And you can drop the wrapping `^` and `$` when calling `matches()`"

```
if (input.matches("(?!a$)[a-z]+")) {
    // it's an all-lowercase string, but not "a"
}
```

Of course you don't need regex. although it's a little long winded:

```
if (input.equals(input.toLowerCase()) && !input.equals("a"))
```

but you can read it more easily.

Comment: I think you're the only one who understood what OP wants.

Comment: This really does what I was trying to do initially. Unfortunately this was not the question, but +1 anyways. And the last line is not really of any help, since this is just an example and There will be quite a bunch of strings I need to exclude, but the first line helped!

Comment: @neuron yes you can chain up the negative look aheads, eg to exclude "foo", "bar" and "baz", use: `^(?!(foo|bar|baz)$)[a-z]+$` - see [demo](http://rubular.com/r/bEoXCOXjz3)

Answer (score 0):

Character Class Intersection *is* supported in Java. The problem is that inside a character class, `*` looses its special meaning and the *literal* star "*" will be matched instead. Your regex should be:

```
[a-z&&[^a]]*
```

Now it'll match all characters in the range "a-z" except the "a" character.

---

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z&&[^a]]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("a");
System.out.println(m.matches()); // false
```

Comment: but it still doesn't match `"abc"` ;(

Comment: @Neuron Because "a" is there, isn't this what you want?

Comment: self quoting: >"To me it seemed logical that this would match all lower case strings, expect the string \"a\"".. This is pretty much what I want..

Comment: But the actual question was not "how do i achieve this" anyways, so it's not really relevant

Comment: @Neuron "*To me it seemed logical that this would match all lower case strings, expect the string \"a\"*" - this is exactly what the above code is doing. I don't understand your question then. Isn't the "* looses its meaning.." enough clear?

Comment: no, it doesn't match `"abc"`! I just want don't want to catch `"a"`

Comment: @Neuron then your approach is wrong, you should use lookarounds instead (if you insist to use regex) - see bohemian's answer.

Comment: yes, this seems to do the trick! thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `*` outside of class:

`[[a-z]&&[^a]]*`

Interception of two character classes gives you another character class.
And as said in other answers, `*` doesn't mean quantity inside class. So, use it outside.

Comment: thanks for the attempt, but that was not the question. Also it doesn't match `"abc"`